# Error:Execution failed for task :buildNative in linux

Tags: android, android-ndk, build.gradle, bazel

Recently I have updated my AS to 2.2.3 and I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':buildNative'. 
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''

i am an *UBUNTU* user and this is my **build.gradle**:

```
def bazel_location = '/usr/local/bin/bazel'
def cpuType = 'armeabi-v7a'
def nativeDir = 'libs/' + cpuType

project.buildDir = 'gradleBuild'
getProject().setBuildDir('gradleBuild')

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

buildscript {
    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', '../../contrib/android/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '24.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Support libraries
    compile("com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
    compile("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion") {
        force = true;
    }
//    compile("com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion") {
//        force = true;
//    }
    compile("com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion")
    compile("com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibraryVersion")

    // RxAndroid
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'

    // Glide
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}

task buildNative(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '../../..'
    commandLine bazel_location, 'build', '-c', 'opt', \
      'tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_native_libs', \
       '--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool', \
       '--cpu=' + cpuType, \
       '--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain'
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from('../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android') { include '**/*.so' }
    into nativeDir
    duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
}

copyNativeLibs.dependsOn buildNative
assemble.dependsOn copyNativeLibs
assembleDebug.dependsOn copyNativeLibs
`
```

Comment: Have you installed bazel? To quote the comment directly above the section you posted:
```Note that Bazel is still used to compile the native libs, and must be
installed at the location noted below. This build configuration merely
automates the process of calling out to it and copying the compiled
libraries back into the appropriate directory.```

See tensorflow/examples/android/README.md for instructions on installing bazel and using it to build.

Comment: yes i have already installed bazel before building the app

Comment: What does running "/usr/local/bin/bazel version" on the command line return?

Comment: Build label: 0.4.3
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Thu Dec 22 12:31:25 2016 (1482409885)
Build timestamp: 1482409885
Build timestamp as int: 1482409885